# How to write a test that checks for multiple types in chai

Tags: unit-testing, chai

I'm trying to write a test that would pass if the input is either a string or a null value

in chai is there something similar to

```
expect(foo).to.be.a('string').or.a('null')
```

If not what would be best practice when writing a test that needs to check for multiple types?

Answer (score 11):

This would probably be the easiest way as there is no `or` keyword.

```
var str = null;

expect(str).to.satisfy(function(s){
    return s === null || typeof s == 'string'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Chai provides a [oneOf](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) method which takes an array of possible matches. 
The OP's assertion where the type could either be a string or a null could therefore be coded like this...

```
expect(type(foo)).to.be.oneOf(['string', null])
```

Comment: `oneOf` method is checking values, not types. In this case, it expects `foo` to equal either to 'string' or null.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right Ani. I've corrected the code to assert against type(value) instead of just value.

Comment: The [type-detect](https://github.com/chaijs/type-detect) module is also required.

Comment: @WillP,  ```typeof null ``` is 'object' and not null, so ur decision is not right

Answer (score 1):

I would write like

```js
try {
  expect(foo).to.be.a('string');
} catch (e) {
  expect(foo, 'expected a string or').to.be.a('null');
}
```

output would be

```
AssertionError: expected a string or: expected 100 to be a null
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Will P answer and by @Dima comment I eventually ended up with a utility function

```
function getType(value) {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) return null
  
  const type = typeof(value)
  
  if (type == 'object') {
     if (value instanceof Array) return 'array'
     if (value instanceof Date) return 'date'
  }

  return type
}
```

that can be used like this

```
expect(getType(whatever)).to.be.oneOf(['number', null])
```

I find it very easy to use and extend while keeping my test units clear and understandable. This function can be also extended to support more types

Answer (score 0):

The first argument you pass into chai's `assert` is an expression, so you can do this:

`assert(assert.isString(foo) || assert.isNull(foo), 'must be a string or null');`

Comment: assert throws an error, but this example is assuming it returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
var str = null;
expect(str).to.satisfies(output=>!output); // testcase will pass

var str = '';
expect(str).to.satisfies(output=>!output); // testcase will pass

var str = 'test';
expect(str).to.satisfies(output=>!output); // testcase will fail
```